# Linux Mint 18 - Cinnamon keeps crashing

Tags: linux, linux-mint, cinnamon

This morning Cinnamon won't start and keeps crashing.

It is the dialog that says it crashed and if I would like to restart; click yes and it crashes again.

[Cinnamon crashed after nvidia drivers installation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86336/cinnamon-crashed-after-nvidia-drivers-installation)  Discusses installing ppa:bumblebee/stable but the post is quite old now, is this still relevant?

Below is the output from `lshw -C video` as root

```
john Desktop # lshw -C video
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d0000000-d0ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:b2000000-b207ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:32 memory:d1000000-d13fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
```

This guy suggested removing the .cinnamon folder from the user directory.

I have to admit, I am reasonably comfortable in the Linux server world, but quite new to Linux desktop GUIs.

Does anyone have any suggestions on where I should start to debug this? I would rather not have to reinstall the whole OS to fix this!

Comment: Well, did you try removing the `.cinnamon` folder?

Comment: Yup, but no joy.. does the same thing.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation

This solved the issue.

Comment: Please write the answer to your question, explaining in your words what happened.

Answer (score 1):

wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation This solved the issue.

Not really got any idea why Bumblebee works over the official nVidia drivers, but install it and reboot and cinnamon magically works again.

If anyone wants to explain why.. would love to know ;)...  @Rui F Ribeiro