# How do I avoid "Cinnamon just crashed ... running in Fallback Mode"?

Tags: debian, drivers, nvidia, cinnamon, nouveau

I'm running Devuan 2.0 (ASCII, same as Debian 9 Stretch basically), and have manually installed nVIDIA CUDA 9.2 and its accompanying drivers (version 396.26).

My system has on-boars Intel graphics, which I actually use, and an nVIDIA GPU, which I only use for compute work (but does have display output ports). Specifically:

```
$ inxi -G
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Device 5912
           Card-2: NVIDIA GK106 [GeForce GTX 650 Ti Boost]
           Display Server: X.Org 1.19.2 drivers: modesetting,nvidia,nouveau (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz
           GLX Renderer: N/A GLX Version: N/A
```

Before installing CUDA, Cinnamon was running. Also, I would really rather the X server not load the nvidia driver nor the nouveau drivers, just whatever is useful for the on-board graphics - and if I managed that it's possible the problem would be resolved. Finally, other apps have been complaining about the inavailability of both GLX and EGL, an issue which may or may not be related.

I have tried preventing the loading of nouveau drivers using `/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-installer-disable-nouveau.conf`, which on my system contains:

```
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
blacklist lbm-nouveau
alias nouveau off
alias lbm-nouveau off
```

but after issuing `su update-initramfs -u` and rebooting, I see no change.

**Related questions:**

- Similar title, but in a different setting and from several years ago: [Cinnamon crashed after nvidia drivers installation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86336/cinnamon-crashed-after-nvidia-drivers-installation).
- Questions about disabling Nouveau:

  - [How do I disable the Nouveau kernel driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112302/how-do-i-disable-the-nouveau-kernel-driver) (AskUbuntu)
  - [Disable Nouveau before Installation](https://superuser.com/questions/1192347/disable-nouveau-before-installation) (SuperUser)
  - [Installing nVIDIA drivers on CentOS - Can't disable Nouveau](https://superuser.com/questions/1152395/installing-nvidia-drivers-on-new-centos-install-cant-blacklist-nouveau) (SuperUser)